# Upper bound for the following function?

Tags: functions

Consider the functions:

$$f(S(t), I(t)) = \frac{\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi) I(t)}{1+\alpha_1 S(t)+\alpha_2 I(t) +\alpha_1 \alpha_2 S(t) I(t)},$$
$$g(S(t), I(t)) = \frac{\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi) S(t)}{1+\alpha_1 S(t)+\alpha_2 I(t) +\alpha_1 \alpha_2 S(t) I(t)},$$

where $\beta>0, 0<\rho<1, 0<\xi<1, \alpha_1, \alpha_2 $ are positive constants and variables $S(t)\geq 0$ and $I(t)\geq 0$.

Maybe the following holds(?): $$f(S,I) \leq \frac{\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi)}{\alpha_2},$$ $$g(S,I) \leq \frac{\beta(1-\rho)(1-\xi)}{\alpha_1},$$
For the f(S, I) bound:

```
Expre78 = (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) i)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i) - 
 (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α2;
vars = Variables[Level[Expre78, {-1}]];

Assuming[
 Element[vars, PositiveReals] && 0 < ξ < 1 && 0 < ρ < 1, 
  (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) i)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i) - (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α2 <= 0 
   // FullSimplify]
(*True*)
```

For the g(S, I) bound:

```
Expre79 = (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) s)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i) - 
 (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α1;
vars = Variables[Level[Expre79, {-1}]];

Assuming[
 Element[vars, PositiveReals] && 0 < ξ < 1 && 0 < ρ < 1, 
  (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) s)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i) - (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α1 <= 0 
   // FullSimplify]
(*True*)
```

But can one verify that this is indeed correct?

Comment: Is this a mathematical question, or a question about how to check the inequality with Wolfram Mathematica? If latter, then you should provide appropriate Mathematica code for your expressions.

Comment: It is the latter, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What I mean is: Instead of LaTeX, use Mathematica code ``f = β (1 - ρ) (1 - ζ) I / (1 + ...)``. Given your previous questions, this is certainly something you know how to do :)

Comment: @Domen Yeah, i just tried :) Can you verify it is indeed correct!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I recommend that your code more closely track your equations. It is then easier to check that you have implemented the code correctly.

```
f[s_, i_] = (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) i)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i);

g[s_, i_] = (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ) s)/(1 + α1 s + α2 i + α1 α2 s i);

cons = {β > 0, 0 < ρ < 1, 0 < ξ < 1, α1 > 0, α2 > 0, s >= 0, i >= 0};

Assuming[cons, f[s, i] <= (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α2 // Simplify]

(* True *)

Assuming[cons, g[s, i] <= (β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ))/α1 // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Note that by specifying that all variables are positive reals, you were changing the constraints on `s` and `i` from nonnegative to positive.